# Error in google healthcare when trying to create a dicom store

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-healthcare

I leave the link as a guide https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/dicom-connect-pacs#creating_a_dicom_store

Deploying the adapter using Google Kubernetes Engine

my manifest file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dicom-adapter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dicom-adapter
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dicom-import-adapter
          image: gcr.io/cloud-healthcare-containers/healthcare-api-dicom-dicomweb-adapter-import:0.2.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2575
              protocol: TCP
              name: "port"
          args:
            - "--dimse_aet=IMPORTADAPTER"
            - "--dimse_port=2575"
            - "--dicomweb_address=https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID/dicomStores/DICOM_STORE_ID/dicomWeb" `
```

In console

```
$kubectl apply -f dicom_adapter.yaml
error: unable to recognize "dicom_adapter.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta"
```

Comment: `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` => `apiVersion: apps/v1 `

Comment: when applying the correction mark error in 'spec:'  
in console -> 
error: error validating "dicom_adapter.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore thes
e errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Answer (score 0):

In your yaml file change `apiVersion` from `extensions/v1beta1` to  `apps/v1`.

In official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/):

> Deployment in the **extensions/v1beta1**, **apps/v1beta1**, and
> **apps/v1beta2** API versions is no longer served
>
> - Migrate to use the  **apps/v1**  API version, available since v1.9. Existing persisted data can be retrieved/updated via the new
>   version.

In new version of Kubernetes there are changes:

- Creating the cluster (k8s cluster in 1.15 version not longer available in GKE)
- Configuring the Deployment: starting from k8s clusters 1.16 version - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 not longer available migrate to use the apps/v1 API version, available since v1.9.
  see doc: [api-deprecations-in-1-16/](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNHKmoOmdU7Lpmu4gIWcXChLs1A7cg)

This issue is raised here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185205137

Also under `spec` section in your `deployment` configuration you have to use `selector` field with `matchLabels` section. In your case part of deployment should look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dicom-adapter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dicom-adapter
    spec:
      selector:  
        matchLabels:  
          app: dicom-adapter
```

the `selector: matchLabels` tells the resource, whatever it may be, service, deployment, etc, to match the pod, according to that label.

Take a look on official documentation -  [kubernetes-object-labels-selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).

Comment: when applying the correction mark error in 'spec:'  
in console --->
error: error validating "dicom_adapter.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore thes
e errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: Have you checked proper example of deployments https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/ ? Try to add selector section and then define template with label.

Comment: I have updated my answer - please take a look.